# Nuxtjs Sidebar routing

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on a simple dashboard. trying to make a sidebar static and just the main section dynamic.

Successfully made the sidebar static but the elements on the new page route of the nuxt link appear under the sidebar instead of the main page section.

PS. I'm using bulma as my CSS framework.

Here's the side bar code.

```html
<template>
  <div class="ml-6 mt-6">
    <div class="columns is-gapless">
      <div class="column is-one-fifth">
        <aside class="menu">
          <ul class="menu-list">
            <li class="py-4">
              <NuxtLink to="/dashboard">
                Dashboard
              </NuxtLink>
            </li>
            <li class="py-4">
              <NuxtLink to="/clients">
                Clients
              </NuxtLink>
            </li>
            <li class="py-4">
              <NuxtLink to="/projects">
                Projects
              </NuxtLink>
            </li>
            <li class="py-4">
              <NuxtLink to="/invoice">
                Invoice
              </NuxtLink>
            </li>
            <li class="py-4">
              <a>Proposal</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </aside>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SideBar'
}
</script>
```

And here's the code for one of the pages I'm trying to route to.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>
      Testing Clients
    </h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ClientS',
  layout: 'sidebar'
}
</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zLp1.png)

what do I do to make the contents on the pages show up in the main section area instead of under the sidebar?

Comment: you need to structure the dom/html so `<nuxt/>` contains just the page content

Answer (score 1):

Include a `<Nuxt />` component in the sidebar layout. It indicates where the page's content is loaded. Learn more on it from [the docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/layouts/).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a layout file named sidebar in the layouts directory. In this file, you can put your sidebar component and `<Nuxt/>` component as your page content.

This is the simple example:

`/layouts/sidebar.vue`

```html
<div>
  <Sidebar />
  <div>
    <Nuxt />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case, you need three files in nuxt project.

1. layout file

in /layout/... directory.

the defualt.vue not require to add to project and used by default.
 is where the pages run.

2. page file

in /pages/... directory.

any .vue files in this directory use default.vue layout by default.

3. component of sidebar or any layout file

in /components/... directory

use can create any .vue file in this directory and use it in layout or page file with syntax

example of layout file with bluma:
(create PanelNavbar and PanelSidebar component With your own taste.)

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <div class="header has-background-white is-flex is-justify-content-flex-end" >
      <PanelNavbar /> 
    </div>

    <section class="main-content is-flex is-justify-content-center">
      <PanelSidebar />
      <div class="column px-0 pt-0">
        <div class="navbar header has-background-dark is-flex is-justify-content-flex-end">
        </div>
        <nuxt />
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>
```